# For loop to match desired record value in array

Tags: perl

I want to print those record has which has 5 pipe delimiter and first name matches to CHINA.
I have tried below method but no output.

```
my @country_records = (
    'CHINA|hk|UK|pak|ind|arg',
    'HK|UK|Pak|ARG|Nep',
    'Lon|WC|Chile|SA',
    'CHINA|hk|UK|pak|arg|ind',
    'CHINA|AFg|UK|pak|arg',
);

for my $item (@county_records) {
    my $value =  q( awk -F '|' -v string=CHINA 'NF == 5 && $item == string' );
    my $record = system($value);
    print $item;
}
```

Comment: You never pass any input to `awk`. You never retrieve any output from `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to invoke awk for this:

```
my @items = split /\|/, $item, -1;
if ((@items == 6) && ($items[0] eq 'CHINA')) {
    print $item;
}
```

`split` on the `|` character then check it gives 6 items and the first one is `CHINA`.

Answer (score 1):

Not AWK, using Perl regex match:

```
my @counrty_records = (
    'CHINA|hk|UK|pak|ind|arg'
  , 'HK|UK|Pak|ARG|Nep'
  , 'Lon|WC|Chile|SA'
  , 'CHINA|hk|UK|pak|arg|ind'
  , 'CHINA|AFg|UK|pak|arg'
);

foreach ( @counrty_records ) {
  print $_ . '<br>' if $_ =~ /^CHINA(\|[^\|]*){5}$/;
}
```

Loop through array of pipe delimited records, print those records starting with "CHINA" (case sensitive), and followed by 5 pipe delimiters, each delimiter followed by 0 or more non-pipe characters.

If you prefer to match CHINA case insensitive, then add the "i" modifier:

```
/^CHINA(\|[^\|]*){5}$/i
```